# Scrollbar to div element in jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am putting scrollbar to div element,below is my code

i have function which assigns text to it

```
$.each(obj, function(index,value) { 
                displayStringAppData = displayStringAppData+'<xmp>'+value+'</xmp>';
                          $("#configWindow").html('<br>'+displayStringAppData);
                showRCModal('configWindow', 400, 700);
            });
```

where

```
function showRCModal(divId, height, width) {
    var rcModel = "";
    $('#'+divId).modal({
        onShow: function() {
            rcModel = this ;
        },
        onClose : function() {
            rcModel.close();
        }
    });
    $("#simplemodal-container").css({'height':height,'width':width,'padding':'0','border':'0'}); 
    $(window).trigger('resize.simplemodal'); 
    return rcModel;
}
```

but scroll is not coming.What should i do.Please help me

Comment: add this in your css:     overflow: scroll;

Comment: @HudsonPH  'overflow':'scroll' i used in css no luck

Comment: @HudsonPH  if i increase height and weight scroll comes showRCModal('configWindow', 600, 1000); but it will be too big to screen.Is there any other way

Comment: can you check the css of the element? (press f12) check this element simplemodal-container

Answer (score 0):

use overflow:scroll property with simplemodal-container css function

Comment: 'overflow':'scroll' i used in css no luck

Comment: ok, did you put your css function in side onShow? If no Please try.

Comment: i used here     $("#simplemodal-container").css({'height':height,'width':width,'padding':'0','border':'0','overflow': 'scroll';});

Comment: put it 
$("#simplemodal-container").css({'height':height,'width':width,'padding':'0','bo‌​rder':'0','overflow': 'scroll';});

in side onShow function

Comment: same thing i have used.